# How to set focus on the first row in interactive in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, apex-code

Source of my InteractiveGrid is query with one parameter . This parameter comes from SelectList.  So every time when I change value of SelectList, InteractiveGrid is refreshed (by dynamic action) and data are changing. All is fine but what I would like to do more is after refresh InteractiveGrid set focus on the first record of this grid.

Any hints please ?

K.

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate interactive grid's property:

[image]

Comment: well, this option is checked but neither on load nor after refresh first row got focus :(

Comment: Hm. Where is the focus, then? Nowhere at all, or somewhere else?

Comment: Still on SelectList.

Comment: I suppose I need second dynamic action. Probably It could be a JavaScript Code which set the focus on IG and do something like GetSelectedRecord=0.     BTW.  Dynamic Action SetFocus does not allow to set focus on region (in my case IG) :(